# sending MySQL database data to objective-c

Tags: iphone, mysql, objective-c, database, xcode

I have been searching far and wide across the web, and I have not yet found a meaty tutorial on how to go about the following process:

Remote MySQL db hosted on webhost, use a webservice to send data over to iPhone, then parse data into objective-c objects for use in-app...

Why is this not documented anywhere? How do people normally deal with such a situation?

Comment: Why not use an intermediate data transfer solution like JSON? then parse with the json-framework?

Comment: That is exactly what I am currently implementing, using [touchJSON](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchJSON). My problem is that I don't know how to convert my data into custom-class objects. Can I do this through touchJSON? Right now my data is all stored in NSDictionaries, so is that good enough? Do I even need to convert my data into objects?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this tutorial. It should give you everything you need to get started with server communication in iOS:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app